# Can post_nav_link navigation work with WordPress custom page templates?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I am using custom page templates to structure different blog layouts in my WordPress theme that I want to sell. Everything is functioning fine except the post_nav_link navigation (previous post | next post). The wordpress codex says that post_nav_links won't work with custom page templates, but I really don't want to start all over again. Is there anything I can do to make post_nav_link navigation work with custom page templates?

Codex Refernece: http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links

Comment: Are they pages or posts? Have you tried the suggestion at the bottom of the codex?

Comment: IF I'm correct next and previous don't work on pages but only on posts.
Based on what do you want to navigate?

Comment: @ChristianVarga yes I have tried the solution at the bottom of the page, but it then turns my blog post navigation into a page-to-page navigation. For example, I'll click next page and it will take me to my contact page instead of the next page of blog posts.

Comment: @janw I have set my custom blog page templates to display only 3 posts per page. I want to implement pagination so that the user can navigate to the pages that contain older and newer posts.

Comment: Ah now I get it. I'll get back at you later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works for my custom template, you might need to add args to `query_posts` but the key is an offset.

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged');

$offset = 0;
if ($paged != 0 ) {
    //$paged -1 because there is no page 1, just 0 and 2 And page 0 is skipped
    $offset = ($paged-1) * get_query_var('posts_per_page') ;
}
query_posts('offset=' . $offset);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
       // the loop
```

and for the pagination:

```
<div id="pagination">
    <div id="pagination-previous"><?php previous_posts_link('previous'); ?></div>
    <div id="pagination-next"><?php next_posts_link('next'); ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry to annoy you with this again janw but I think I jumped the gun on this one. Your method works fine for my home.php file, but when I turn that file into a page template by adding the "<?php /* Template name: */ ?> line of code to the top of the file and set it as a custom template to a page, the pagination fails to work.

Comment: Take a look at this question and my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121230/can-post-nav-link-navigation-work-with-wordpress-custom-page-templates/10139530#10139530

Comment: The post template that contains your code works, however only when I set the page with the post template as the static front page from the Settings > Reading panel inside Wordpress, the pagination fails to work. I have to do this so the page appears when the responsive mobile navigation container is activated

Comment: This issue still stands. I'm very sure it has to do with issues brought up here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-30-bug-with-pagination-when-using-static-page-as-homepage-1?replies=21 and here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13471

I've tested solutions from both sources and I just can't get any of them  to work. Please help!

Comment: okay step back. My code only works, but not on a (static) homepage? right?

Comment: okay. First I will look into it, I'm curious about the problem. Second I'm a bit disappointed that you pulled the 'accepted' from my answer. Your question wasn't original about the hompage with custom template. It was just about a custom template. The least you could do is give me a up vote.

Comment: Sorry janw. To make it up for you I've opened up a separate post containing this question. I'll be happy to give more points to you if you can figure it out! 

Question link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431566/pagination-not-functioning-with-static-homepage-custom-page-template

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @janw, I will try this in the morning. Before I do so, can you cofirm with me if this is the right way to PHP tag the first lot of code?

```
        <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=3"); ?> <!-- Do I keep this line? -->
        <?php $paged = get_query_var('paged'); ?>
        <?php $offset = 0;
        if ($paged != 0 ) {
            //$paged -1 because there is no page 1, just 0 and 2 And page 0 is skipped
            $offset = ($paged-1) * get_query_var('posts_per_page') ;
        } ?>
        <?php query_posts('offset=' . $offset); ?>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Hi James skip the first line it shouldn't matter but it's just ugly. Also don't close and open `<?php`,`?>` if there is no `HTML` between them it's just ugly and it (a bit) slower.

Also if My answer is the right one accept my answer.