# Wordpress two category loops with sticky on start page. Pagination error

Tags: wordpress, pagination, sticky

hope you guys can help me.

I have two very simple custom loops from one category: one sticky, one non-sticky. I want the sticky posts to only display on the first page, and not on the rest of the pages when I paginate. There must also be exactly 8 post (including the Sticky posts on page 1) on every page. All this is working fine with the code I got below.

The problem is this: Page one: 1 sticky & posts #15-**9**, pages two: post #**7**-1. WP skips one post (#8) on the second page because of the sticky post. Anyone got a solution for this? I would appreciate the help very much.

```
<!-- Sticky -->
<?php if ( $paged != True ): ?>
    <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'category_name' => Work)); ?>
        <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
<?php endif ?>

<?php 
$postcount = $wp_query->post_count; 
$postnumber = 8; 
if ( $paged != True ){ $postnumber = $postnumber - $postcount; }
?>

<!-- Non-Sticky -->
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'), 'category_name' => Work, 'posts_per_page' => $postnumber, 'paged' => $paged)); ?>
    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at my answer to a similar question here:
[Can post_nav_link navigation work with WordPress custom page templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121230/can-post-nav-link-navigation-work-with-wordpress-custom-page-templates/10139530#10139530)
the key is `offset`

Comment: Thanks for the answer janw! I willl try that and let you know how it went.

Comment: I cant really get it to work. Dosent this: `$offset = ($paged-1) * get_query_var('posts_per_page')` equal 8 if Im on page 2 and posts_per_page is 8?

Comment: yes, the if you have 8 posts per page. Then you want page 2 to have an offset of 8 (page 2 starts at nr 9)